# why does javascript render removed components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, use-effect

Guys I'm working on a project now and I have a component that is returned by antd `Menu` item. It has 4 components: `Home`, `Username`, `Login`, and `Register`:

```
const items = [
        {
          label: <Link to='/'>Home </Link>, //- {JSON.stringify(user)}
          key: 'home',
          icon: <AppstoreOutlined />,
        },
        {
          label: 'Username',
          key: 'SubMenu',
          icon: <SettingOutlined />,
          children: [
            {
              label: 'Option 1',
              key: 'setting:1',
            },
            {
              label: 'Option 2',
              key: 'setting:2',
            },
            {
              label: <item onClick={logout}>Logout</item>,
              key: 'setting:3',
              icon: <LogoutOutlined />
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          label: <Link to='/register'>Register</Link>,
          key: 'register',
          icon: <UserAddOutlined />,
          style: { marginLeft: 1030},   // problem: hard-coded margin
        },
        {
          label: <Link to='/login'>Login</Link>,
          key: 'login',
          icon: <UserOutlined />,
          style: { marginLeft: 'auto'},
        },      
      ];
    
    useEffect(() => {
      if (user) {  // "user" is an object returned by userSelector
        items.splice(2, 2);
      }
    }, [user]);
    console.log(items);
    
    return <Menu  onClick={handleClick} selectedKeys={[current]} mode="horizontal" items={items} />;
```

As you can see, I'm using a `useEffect` hook here. If the user is not logged in (so `user === null`), then the if statements in `useEffect` will not be executed; otherwise the `Login` and `Register` components in the array `items` will be removed and hidden, and only the first 2 are left.

From `console.log(items);` we can see what `items` is like currently. When a user is logged in, it does have only two components:
[image]

However, we can still see `Login` and `Register` are there in such a circumstance:
[image]

So why do JS and React render removed components?

Comment: `items.splice(2, 2);` You are  mutating the object! React does not have magical power to re render when the value of a variable change. You have to trigger or schedule the state update by using `setState`. so use `useState` to hold your data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use "useState" hook to make the UI update, in you example, the items will be updated, but the UI will not update.

```
import { useState } from 'react'
const [items, setItems] = useState([
    {
      label: <Link to='/'>Home </Link>, //- {JSON.stringify(user)}
      key: 'home',
      icon: <AppstoreOutlined />,
    },
    {
      label: 'Username',
      key: 'SubMenu',
      icon: <SettingOutlined />,
      children: [
        {
          label: 'Option 1',
          key: 'setting:1',
        },
        {
          label: 'Option 2',
          key: 'setting:2',
        },
        {
          label: <item onClick={logout}>Logout</item>,
          key: 'setting:3',
          icon: <LogoutOutlined />
      },
      ],
    },
    {
      label: <Link to='/register'>Register</Link>,
      key: 'register',
      icon: <UserAddOutlined />,
      style: { marginLeft: 1030},   // problem: hard-coded margin
    },
    {
      label: <Link to='/login'>Login</Link>,
      key: 'login',
      icon: <UserOutlined />,
      style: { marginLeft: 'auto'},
    },      
  ]);

useEffect(() => {
  if (user) {  // "user" is an object returned by userSelector
    setItems((items) => {
        items.splice(2, 2);
        return items;
    }
  }
}, [user]);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need the re render to be happened. You can store the array in a state. If you store the array in normal javascript variable. React will not re render the component. Try like I given below,

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([
        {
          label: <Link to='/'>Home </Link>, //- {JSON.stringify(user)}
          key: 'home',
          icon: <AppstoreOutlined />,
        },
        {
          label: 'Username',
          key: 'SubMenu',
          icon: <SettingOutlined />,
          children: [
            {
              label: 'Option 1',
              key: 'setting:1',
            },
            {
              label: 'Option 2',
              key: 'setting:2',
            },
            {
              label: <item onClick={logout}>Logout</item>,
              key: 'setting:3',
              icon: <LogoutOutlined />
          },
          ],
        },
        {
          label: <Link to='/register'>Register</Link>,
          key: 'register',
          icon: <UserAddOutlined />,
          style: { marginLeft: 1030},   // problem: hard-coded margin
        },
        {
          label: <Link to='/login'>Login</Link>,
          key: 'login',
          icon: <UserOutlined />,
          style: { marginLeft: 'auto'},
        },      
      ]);
    
    useEffect(() => {
      if (user) {  // "user" is an object returned by userSelector
        setItems(items.splice(2, 2));
      }
    }, [user]);
    console.log(items);
  
    return <Menu  onClick={handleClick} selectedKeys={[current]} mode="horizontal" items={items} />;
```